# How to change home button image in wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello friends,
          Actually i was new to wordpress website development. So i am facing a problem. I want to change the image of a home button located on top menu bar which open's the home page of my website. I want to change it with the logo of my website.

My webpage is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ZYgqpGqmsdbUdvLUk0eU0zS0U/view?usp=sharing

In the above i want to replace the "MUSE" text to a image/logo of my company and when i click on this image it open's the home page of my website.. Please help me guys..

What i actually want is like this site :

http://www.sikhchannel.tv/

They are using their website's logo on which when user clicks, it open's home page.

Comment: What theme are you using? Most WordPress themes support this in the backend of the website. Otherwise, you could try Appearance -> Customize and change the logo there.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own custom menu from “Appearance => Menu”. You can change the menu name from the labels of the items.

Source: google.com

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it seems you're using the "Muse" theme.

You should find the logo upload in the theme configurator: http://docs.grandpixels.com/muse/#theme-customizer